# multiple depth exceeded in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, konvajs, react-konva

I am trying to create multiple selection of shapes using transformer of react konva. I want to pass multiple nodes to Transformer. while doing this, i am getting `multiple depth exceeded`error. i am using a shape ref from the child component and setting it's value. It is with React hooks.

I've commented the `setNodes(temp)` line. works fine without this. but i want to set it to `setNodes`.

Here is the demo sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-selection-react-hooks-and-konva-fq3fs?file=/src/index.js:3746-3760).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making infinite loop in this line:

```
onClick={onSelect(shapeRef)}
```

Probably you need this instead:

```js
onClick={() => onSelect(shapeRef)}
```

Comment: You're Right. It's Working. but can you help why the shape is getting selected on double click or on ctrl+ select. I've updated my demo.

Comment: Above is solved too, now the other thing is, i added the mouse move up and down functions as you mentioned on documentation. but the selection through mouse is not working. please check demo. must be some minor mistake but i am very messed up and don't know what's wrong

Comment: You can answer it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63466701/selection-of-shapes-using-mouse-drag-and-drop-not-working-react-konva