# Selection of shapes using mouse drag and drop not working - React Konva

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, konvajs, react-konva

I am trying to create a multiple shape selection using `Transformer` of `React konva`. It is working well with the mouse click on one shape and then to other shape, creates a whole selection of both shapes. i want this to be achieved by mouse drag and drop. for which i wrote mouse up,down and move and click functions on stage which are mentioned in the [documentation](https://konvajs.org/docs/select_and_transform/Basic_demo.html). there is no errors but mouse drag selection is not working. I want the selection to work exactly same as given on documentation demo.

Here is my demo sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-selection-react-hooks-and-konva-fq3fs?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: So what are you saying - you copied & pasted a demo into your own code and it does not work?  Please review what you did, it would seem that you either introduced a bug or do not understand some aspect of the demo.  In general terms, posting a link to 290 dense lines of off-site code is not likely to achieve a quick answer here.  You need to do the work to produce a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue before many folks will get involved.

Comment: No, i haven't just copied and pasted, the demo (https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Transformer.html) wasn't for multiple selection of shapes it was for selection of one shape and transformer demo only. i  took reference of many code and made the above one. and i reviewed it many times but not able to find. that's why i asked.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for motivating me to review it again. i got it solved. just a small bug now. while i select the shape, it is taking extra space. i think the error is in this line ---- var shapes = stage.find("Rect").toArray(); ---- can you tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. My way:

```js
  const selectionRectRef = React.useRef();
  const selection = React.useRef({
    visible: false,
    x1: 0,
    y1: 0,
    x2: 0,
    y2: 0
  });

  const updateSelectionRect = () => {
    const node = selectionRectRef.current;
    node.setAttrs({
      visible: selection.current.visible,
      x: Math.min(selection.current.x1, selection.current.x2),
      y: Math.min(selection.current.y1, selection.current.y2),
      width: Math.abs(selection.current.x1 - selection.current.x2),
      height: Math.abs(selection.current.y1 - selection.current.y2),
      fill: "rgba(0, 161, 255, 0.3)"
    });
    node.getLayer().batchDraw();
  };

  const oldPos = React.useRef(null);
  const onMouseDown = (e) => {
    const isElement = e.target.findAncestor(".elements-container");
    const isTransformer = e.target.findAncestor("Transformer");
    if (isElement || isTransformer) {
      return;
    }

    const pos = e.target.getStage().getPointerPosition();
    selection.current.visible = true;
    selection.current.x1 = pos.x;
    selection.current.y1 = pos.y;
    selection.current.x2 = pos.x;
    selection.current.y2 = pos.y;
    updateSelectionRect();
  };

  const onMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (!selection.current.visible) {
      return;
    }
    const pos = e.target.getStage().getPointerPosition();
    selection.current.x2 = pos.x;
    selection.current.y2 = pos.y;
    updateSelectionRect();
  };

  const onMouseUp = () => {
    oldPos.current = null;
    if (!selection.current.visible) {
      return;
    }
    const selBox = selectionRectRef.current.getClientRect();

    const elements = [];
    layerRef.current.find(".rectangle").forEach((elementNode) => {
      const elBox = elementNode.getClientRect();
      if (Konva.Util.haveIntersection(selBox, elBox)) {
        elements.push(elementNode);
      }
    });
    trRef.current.nodes(elements);
    selection.current.visible = false;
    // disable click event
    Konva.listenClickTap = false;
    updateSelectionRect();
  };
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-selection-react-hooks-and-konva-forked-tgggi?file=/src/index.js